# Why can't I use a String array with a method taking an Iterable as a parameter?

Tags: java, generics, interface, functional-programming

I'm trying to write my own "functional" little lib in Java. If I have this function :

```
public static <T> List<T> filter(Iterable<T> source,BooleanTest predicate)
{
    List<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(T t : source)
    {
         if(predicate.ok(t))
            results.add(t);
    }
    return results;
}
```

why can't I use it with this snippet:

```
String strings[] = {"one","two","three"};
List<String> containingO = IterableFuncs.filter(strings,new BooleanTest() {
   public boolean ok(String obj) {
     return obj.indexOf("o") != -1;
   }
});
```

As far as I know, a Java array implements Iterable, right? What needs to be changed to make the function work with arrays, as well as collections? By choosing Iterable as the first parameter, I figured I got all cases covered.

Comment: (`Iterable<? extends T> source` would be slightly more general.)

Comment: Don't bother supporting the array/varargs directly; a user can always "import static java.util.Arrays.asList" to get a very easy way to turn varargs into a Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, it's annoying.

You could overload filter() thusly...

```
public static <T> List<T> filter(T[] source, BooleanTest predicate)
{
    return filter(Arrays.asList(source), predicate);
}
```

Comment: A little offtopic, but why would `public static <T> ArrayList<T> filter(T... args,BooleanTest predicate)` give a missing `)` error?

Comment: Because a varargs parameter, if present, must be the last parameter in a method signature.  The compiler is complaining that it doesn't see ')' after 'T... args'

Answer (score 11):

Arrays don't implement any interfaces in Java, unfortunately. The [enhanced for loop](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) works over arrays *and* iterables, separately.

However, you can use [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) to wrap an array in a `List<T>` which is iterable.

In terms of the "functional library" side of things, you should probably have a look at [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) which has a lot of similar stuff in.

Comment: So, I'd need to implement two versions? One taking an `Iterable`, and one taking variable length arguments?

Comment: Or start with a `Collection` in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, but it would be nice to be able to use arrays as well.

Comment: Geo, the excellent book *Java Generics and Collections* basically suggests treating arrays as a deprecated type. For my own API, I would always favor avoiding arrays.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to treat arrays as deprecated - although I would *usually* avoid exposing them. The fact that they can handle primitives efficiently is a definite point in their favour...

Comment: And yes Enum.values() (added in Java 5) bizarrely returns an array. Go figure.

Comment: @cletus: That's particularly annoying, as it means it can't be an immutable singleton... pointless (though small) performance hit every time it's called :(

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays are *not* `Iterable` even though the enhanced `for` loop can iterate over them.

The usual way I handle this is:

```
public void doStuff(String... args) {
  doStuff(Arrays.asList(args));
}
```

and either:

```
public void doStuff(Iterable<String> args) {
  ...
}
```

or:

```
public void doStuff(Collection<String> args) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

arrays are designed to be lightweight. they do not implement iterable.

unfortunately you'll need to overload ie write another version of the same method for the array type or convert it to a collection (which would be less efficient).